# Consider the following topology and determine if the following sets are open or closed. (Need help understanding this topology.)

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau = \left\{A \subset \mathbb{R} : \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \ \ \ \forall n \geq N \ \ \frac{1}{n} \in A\right\} \cup \left\{\emptyset\right\}$.

1. Is [0,5) closed. Why?
2. Is (0,5) open. Why?
3. Is [0,5] open. Why?
4. Is [0,5] closed. Why?
5. Is (0,5] closed. Why?
6. Give an example of an open set which does not contain any interval. Prove your answer.
7. Take $A = (0,1)$, find $A^0,A^a,\overline{A}$
8. Take $A = (1,2)$, find $A^0,A^a,\overline{A}$

Now, I need help understanding what this topology actually is. To my understanding, it consists of subsets of the reals (or the empty set) that contain fractions that satisfy the conditions. I am not sure about this.

Comment: A nonempty set will be called an open set in your topology if and only if contains all but finitely many terms of the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$. From this, 1,2,3,4 and 5 are easy to see.  For 6, take $A=\{\frac{1}{n}: n\in \Bbb N\}$. I don't understand the notation $A^a$ so I can't help with that.

Comment: Luis, why must an open set contain only finite many terms in the sequence 1/n? I don't quite see that restriction.

Comment: @CormanoSanchez: Welcome to SE! Users will be pinged if wherever you comment address them with '@username'. Otherwise it's more a thing about luck wether they will have a look again. There are actually more mechanisms but just that you won't wonder... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let $S := \{\frac{1}{n}: n ∈ \mathbb{N}\}$. Then you can describe the topology as follows: $∅ ≠ A ⊆ X$ is open iff $A ∩ S$ is cofinite in $S$.

Also note that for any non-trivial subset $A ⊆ X$ we have, either $A$ or $X \setminus A$ is open, but not both. So for example $[0, 5)$ cannot be closed, because it's open.